# How to delete specific parameter using their id in Rest Assured?

Tags: json, rest-assured

Below is the json response

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "UserName": "john",
      "id": "abc_123",
      "LastName": "smith"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to delete only the `UserName` parameter :

```
request.delete("http://localhost:8080/details/id/UserName");
```

The above code does not seem to work and my expected is as below

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "id": "abc_123",
      "LastName": "smith"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting a question on SO, There are people to help but we would need to know what you've tried beforehand.

To answer your question, You should use a **PUT** and not a **DELETE** cause you are trying to update the payload. DELETE as the name suggests will delete the complete resource

Check this  [link](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) for more detail

PUT calls are **resource specific** so you will have to mention which entity should be affected.

I have come up with a sample code based on the details you've provided

Used **HashMap** here but you could also post the body **as such** or use **POJO** or **JSONObject**

```
{

    Map < String, Object > map = new HashMap < > ();
    map.put("details", Arrays.asList(new HashMap < String, Object > () {
        {
            put("id", "abc_123");
            put("LastName", "smith");
        }
    }));

    RequestSpecification req = RestAssured.given();
    req.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    req.body(map).when();
    Response resp = req.put("http://localhost:8080/details/id/abc_123");

    String body = resp.asString();
    System.out.println("Response is : " + body);
}
```